# Display PDF in popup

Tags: jquery, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have searched for hours on a way to display a pdf on a modal window, I've seen the posts that have similar issue.
I have made it to display a pdf on a modal window  [as you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udjic.png)

My problem is, I have a list of users (datatable) [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs3tf.png) where you can view the detail of a user and when you click on the "pdf" button, normally you should see the same modal as when you click on the button outside the datatable. I get this error on the web browser [picture3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {






  // ------------------------------------  the datatables script, when clicking on the plus button, it shows more detail, about  -----------------------------------------------


  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": testdata.data,
    select: "single",
    "columns": [{
        "className": 'details-control',
        "orderable": false,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": '',
        "render": function() {
          return '<i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        },
        width: "15px"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "position"
      },
      {
        "data": "office"
      },
      {
        "data": "salary"
      }
    ],
    "order": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var tdi = tr.find("i.fa");
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
      tdi.first().removeClass('fa-minus-square');
      tdi.first().addClass('fa-plus-square');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
      tdi.first().removeClass('fa-plus-square');
      tdi.first().addClass('fa-minus-square');
    }
  });

  table.on("user-select", function(e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
    if ($(cell.node()).hasClass("details-control")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });



});






function format(d) {

  return '<div class="panel panel-primary">' +
    '<div class="panel-heading">' +
    '<h3 class="panel-title">Informations du candidat</h3>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="panel-body">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">' +
    '<img class="img-circle" src="https://openclipart.org/download/211821/matt-icons_preferences-desktop-personal.svg?sz=100" alt="User Pic">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 hidden-md hidden-lg">' +
    '<img class="img-circle" src="https://openclipart.org/download/211821/matt-icons_preferences-desktop-personal.svg?sz=50" alt="User Pic">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 hidden-xs hidden-sm">' +
    '<strong>' + d.name + '</strong><br>' +
    '<table class="table table-user-information">' +
    '<tbody>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Titre: </td>' +
    '<td>' + d.position + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Date de disponibilité:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.start_date + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr> <td>Salair souhaité:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.salary + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
    '<td>Addresse:</td><td>' + d.office + '</td>' +
    '</tr> </tbody></table> </div> </div></div>' +
    '<div class="panel-footer">' +
    '<a class="btn btn-primary voir-pdf" title="Exemple de PDF dans un « modal »" href="files/test.pdf">PDF</a>' +
    ' <span class="pull-right">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip"' +
    'data-original-title="Edit this user"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>' +
    '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button"' +
    'data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove this user"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>' +
    '</span></div></div>';

  /* return '<div class="card b-1 hover-shadow mb-20">' + 
       '<div class="media card-body">' +
            '<div class="media-left pr-12">' +
                '<img class="avatar avatar-xl no-radius" src="https://openclipart.org/download/211821/matt-icons_preferences-desktop-personal.svg" alt="..."></div>' +
            '<div class="media-body">' +
                '<div class="mb-2">' +
                    '<span class="fs-20 pr-16">' + d.name +'</span>'+
               '</div>' +
                '<small class="fs-16 fw-300 ls-1">'+ d.position +'</small>'+
             '</div>' +
            '<div class="media-right text-right d-none d-md-block">' +
                '<p class="fs-14 text-fade mb-12"><i class="fa fa-map-marker pr-1"></i>' + d.office + '</p>' +
                '<span class="text-fade"><i class="fa fa-money pr-1"></i>' + d.salary + '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<footer class="card-footer flexbox align-items-center">' +
            '<div>' +
                '<strong>Applied on:</strong>'+
                '<span>' + d.start_date +'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="card-hover-show">' +
                '<a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-info" href="#">Download CV</a>' +
                '<a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-primary" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact">Contact</a>' +
                '<a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-warning" href="#">Delete</a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</footer>' +
    '</div>'; */

  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  /* return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
       '<tr>' +
           '<td>Nom et prénom:</td>' +
           '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
       '</tr>' +
       '<tr>' +
           '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
           '<td>' + d.extn + '</td>' +
       '</tr>' +
       '<tr>' +
           '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
           '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
       '</tr>' +
   '</table>';   */


}

var testdata = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$327,900",
      "start_date": "2010/10/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "6200"
    },
    {
      "name": "Colleen Hurst",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$205,500",
      "start_date": "2009/09/15",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2360"
    },
    {
      "name": "Caesar Vance",
      "position": "Pre-Sales Support",
      "salary": "$106,450",
      "start_date": "2011/12/12",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8330"
    },
    {
      "name": "Doris Wilder",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$85,600",
      "start_date": "2010/09/20",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "3023"
    },
    {
      "name": "Angelica Ramos",
      "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "salary": "$1,200,000",
      "start_date": "2009/10/09",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "5797"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gavin Joyce",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$92,575",
      "start_date": "2010/12/22",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8822"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jennifer Chang",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$357,650",
      "start_date": "2010/11/14",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "9239"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brenden Wagner",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$206,850",
      "start_date": "2011/06/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1314"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiona Green",
      "position": "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "salary": "$850,000",
      "start_date": "2010/03/11",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2947"
    },
    {
      "name": "Shou Itou",
      "position": "Regional Marketing",
      "salary": "$163,000",
      "start_date": "2011/08/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8899"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michelle House",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$95,400",
      "start_date": "2011/06/02",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "2769"
    },
    {
      "name": "Suki Burks",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$114,500",
      "start_date": "2009/10/22",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6832"
    },
    {
      "name": "Prescott Bartlett",
      "position": "Technical Author",
      "salary": "$145,000",
      "start_date": "2011/05/07",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3606"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gavin Cortez",
      "position": "Team Leader",
      "salary": "$235,500",
      "start_date": "2008/10/26",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2860"
    },
    {
      "name": "Martena Mccray",
      "position": "Post-Sales support",
      "salary": "$324,050",
      "start_date": "2011/03/09",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8240"
    },
    {
      "name": "Unity Butler",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$85,675",
      "start_date": "2009/12/09",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "name": "Howard Hatfield",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$164,500",
      "start_date": "2008/12/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "7031"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hope Fuentes",
      "position": "Secretary",
      "salary": "$109,850",
      "start_date": "2010/02/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6318"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vivian Harrell",
      "position": "Financial Controller",
      "salary": "$452,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Timothy Mooney",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$136,200",
      "start_date": "2008/12/11",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "7580"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "position": "Director",
      "salary": "$645,750",
      "start_date": "2008/09/26",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1042"
    },
    {
      "name": "Olivia Liang",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$234,500",
      "start_date": "2011/02/03",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "2120"
    }
  ]
};
//  les informations de chaque candidat
var panels = $('.user-infos');
var panelsButton = $('.dropdown-user');
panels.hide();

//Click dropdown
panelsButton.click(function() {
  //get data-for attribute
  var dataFor = $(this).attr('data-for');
  var idFor = $(dataFor);

  //current button
  var currentButton = $(this);
  idFor.slideToggle(400, function() {
    //Completed slidetoggle
    if (idFor.is(':visible')) {
      currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up text-muted"></i>');
    } else {
      currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>');
    }
  })
});


$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("This is a demo.\n :-)");
});

/*
 * Le plug-in PDF  script for viewing PDF File
 */
(function(a) {
  a.twModalPDF = function(b) {
    defaults = {
      title: "PDF dans un « modal »",
      message: "Impossible d’ouvrir le document PDF",
      closeButton: true,
      scrollable: false
    };
    var b = a.extend({}, defaults, b);
    var c = (b.scrollable === true) ? 'style="max-height: 1020px;overflow-y: auto;"' : "";
    html = '<div class="modal fade" id="oModalPDF">';
    html += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">';
    html += '<div class="modal-content">';
    html += '<div class="modal-header">';
    html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
    if (b.title.length > 0) {
      html += '<h4 class="modal-title">' + b.title + "</h4>"
    }
    html += "</div>";
    html += '<div class="modal-body" ' + c + ">";
    html += b.message;
    html += "</div>";
    html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    if (b.closeButton === true) {
      html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>'
    }
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    a("body").prepend(html);
    a("#oModalPDF").modal().on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
      a(this).remove()
    })
  }
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
  $('.voir-pdf').on('click', function() {
    var sUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var sTitre = $(this).attr('title');
    var sIframe = '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + sUrl + '" width="100%" height="500">Aucun support</object>';
    $.twModalPDF({
      title: sTitre,
      message: sIframe,
      closeButton: true,
      scrollable: false
    });
    return false;
  });
})
```

```css
td.details-control {
  text-align: center;
  color: forestgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.user-row {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.user-row:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-user {
  margin: 13px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-user:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-user-information>tbody>tr {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.table-user-information>tbody>tr:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.table-user-information>tbody>tr>td {
  border-top: 0;
}

body {
  background: #FCFCFC;
}

.pr-12 {
  padding-right: 12px !important;
}

.mb-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.b-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb !important;
}

.card {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.media {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.media {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.media .avatar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.no-radius {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.avatar-xl {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  color: #8b95a5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
}

.fs-20 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.pr-16 {
  padding-right: 16px !important;
}

.ls-1 {
  letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}

.fw-300 {
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}

.fs-16 {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.media-body>* {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

small,
time,
.small {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #8b95a5;
}

.fs-14 {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.mb-12 {
  margin-bottom: 12px !important;
}

.text-fade {
  color: rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.7) !important;
}

.card-footer:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-footer {
  background-color: #fcfdfe;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.07);
  color: #8b95a5;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.card-footer {
  background-color: #fcfdfe;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.07);
  color: #8b95a5;
  padding: 10px 20px
}

.card-footer>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.hover-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)
}

.fs-10 {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}


/* Style Modal Bootstrap 4 */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #393633;
}

.modal-header {
  border: none;
  background-color: #393633;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.modal-footer .btn-primary {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #393633;
  border-color: #333;
}

.modal-footer .btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #393633;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  



</head>

<body>

  <a class="btn btn-primary voir-pdf" title="Exemple de PDF dans un « modal »" href="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf">PDF</a>


  <table width="100%" class="display" id="example" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7RtD.png) :

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf

and the pdf is displayed on another window

I really don't know what I'm missing :(

Comment: here's the link to my code on codepen:   https://codepen.io/SClarck/pen/MENYEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, I just had to place the code that does the work for the pdf showing after the call of the function that create the user's information panel, I edit the code on codePen  `---<https://codepen.io/SClarck/pen/MENYEL--->`

Now the code is working. You can view a user detail also view its "CV" in popup window, Hope it helps someone.

Best regards